# Two finite graphs with n vertices: Can one have both more components and more edges than the other?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ and $G'$ are two graphs having $n$ vertices.For what values of $n$ is it possible for $G$ to have more components and edges than $G'$?

What could be the possible values of $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=1,2,3,4$ it's not possible.

If $n$ is  $5$ consider $K_4$ with an isolated vertex and $P_5$, one has $6$ edges and $2$ components, the other $4$ edges and $1$ component.

If $n$ is greater than $5$ consider $K_4$ and $n-4$ vertices and $P_5$ with $n-5$ isolated vertices.

Comment: K4 will have 6 edges and P5  will have 4 edges according to above explanation

Comment: Oh yeah, right.

Comment: Still p5 show 5 edges..it should be 4,i think you forgot to edit

Comment: Oh oops, the example still works though :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for $n\ge 5$.

We might have $G'$ connected (so a single component) with as few as $n-1$ edges (tree).

Then $G$ could have an isolated vertex and a clique (complete subgraph) on the remaining $n-1$ vertices.  Now $(n-2)(n-1)/2 \gt n-1$ for $n-2 \gt 2$, i.e. $n \gt 4$.

Comment: We posted almost at the same time  :) (you won by a couple secs)